# SharePoint 2016 Searchable Items : All Error and Index Partition Error

Tags: search, search-results, crawling, onedrive-for-business

I'm currently testing OneDrive For Business function. When I try to use the search bar to search for my document, it gives me error

> Search has encountered a problem that prevents results from being returned. If the issue persists, please contact your administrator.
>
> Correlation ID: 090fe09d-3254-9044-7e2b-e1f3678e7817

When I click on "Recent" or "Shared With Me", Nothing shows up even when I just upload a document 5 seconds ago.

When I go to the Central admin and look through the search service application, under the topology, it shows me this:

[image]

Is it because of the index partition error that causes the problem?

How can I fix this? I read about resetting index but they say it's last resort.
I'm here to find out if there's any other solution.

I am currently using SharePoint 2016 and currently doing it on a VM.

Answer (score 1):

There are any number of reasons why your Search Service Application would be in such bad shape. Without reviewing logs it is had to say exactly what is going wrong. Here are some general ideas.

I would begin with Resources. You say you are running on a VM. With a single server VM you need RAM. 12-16GB for a test/dev server and 24GB for production would be the absolute minimum.

In production, it is a bad practice to run Crawl and Admin together. You should probably reduce the crawler performance to share resources more effectively.

```
Get-SPEnterpriseSearchService | Set-SPEnterpriseSearchService –PerformanceLevel "Reduced" #or "Partly Reduced"
```

You may also just need to set the Service Application Proxy association for the Web Application. For each wen application in your farm select Service Application Connection and be sure your Search Service Application Proxy is checked.

Comment: Hi, i managed to fixed this by resetting the index. My search service works perfectly fine now. thanks !